# Transform normalized Table (1NF) to a nested table in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, nested, transformation, denormalization

Is there any implemented function/procedure in Oracle 11g to simply transform a standard normalized table into a nested table? Or does someone has an idea for the following problem?

Reason: All of our tables are normalized in a way that if a certain attribute value is set twice or more for one record the whole record (except this attribute value)has to be stored redundant. Meaning, if I have in my person table an attribute "ID_CARD_NUMBER" and one person has two nationalities (and two ID cards) there is a second record with redundant attribute values except "ID_CARD_NUMBER". Outsourcing such an attribute in an extra table is NOT an option and I also don't want to denormalize in a way that one attribute value consists of a concatenation of prior, separated attribute values.

Comment: Why is creating a nested table an option for you but putting the ID_CARD_NUMBER data in a separate table, creating a parent child relation, not?

Comment: Your data model is basically broken. I highly recommend you look into 2nd and 3rd normal forms

Comment: No, its not or at least, I guess it is not broken. We have a lot of real world objects and every object has several first level features (470). This first level features are disjoint and do have again second level features (10 to 100 depending on first level features). 70% of all queries will only ask for one first level feature. So I alrady have 470 tables and all of them need to be joined to receive the whole record. See next post...

Comment: Summarizing: I prefer nesting tables instead of normalizing. And even more tables would kill me, because we have a big bunch of sparse records with almost ~2400 possible attributes. Furthermore, 60 to 70% of ALL attributes (second level features) are allocated several times... It seems like I need to take a NoSQL solution (MongoDB), but before I try to solve the problem with Oracle, because we have some licenses ;)

Comment: Nested tables will internally create a child table but have a lot of draw backs. No constraints, triggers, indexes on the child table, no direct access to child data. Making nested tables an integral part of your physical data design will lead you in all kind of troubles. Furthermore 99% of all developers have never used nested tables in this way, 100% know how to use parent-child relations. I'd rather have a large number of tables then an obscure feature like nested tables.

Comment: Ok, BUT: I'm not interested in constraints and triggers and a direct access to a certain element of a nested table. As far as I know indexes on nestes tables do exist (in Oracle 11g)?! And for a large number of my tables it doesnt make sense to divide a table to parent-child tables. Example with a table of 10 attributes: Within this table each attribute will have severall attribut values of the same attribute for the same object. In those cases I would have to create 9 child-tables (first attribute only identifies the object by ID).... 9*470= OMG

Comment: As Steve said, I think your data design is broken. Without a real example I can not help. But again : oracle is a relational database, to make best use of it you'll have to use a relational data design, 3rd NF. I don't see 5000 tables as a problem, if your data modelling leads to 5000 tables, so be it. I'd rather have that then 500 tables with each 10 nested tables in them, resulting in 5000 tables anyway.

Comment: Summary: There is no command of oracle that does what I wanted to do.

Comment: Don't think so, but you could generate create/alter table statements using information in the dictionary.

Comment: I highly recommend that you read a book on data modeling.

Comment: I wont take this hint from someone who recommends taking 3NF in such a case. And by the way: Its also kind of rude...

Comment: @sequil I don't think Steve is being rude, he's giving you good advise. If you need to join 470 tables to get a whole record (object) from the database that should ring some bells. It appears you see the database as 'just a data dump' in which database design is a direct mapping of your application objects. Database design should be a logical representation of your information.

Comment: I dont agree, sorry. Database model design and database model choice should be a well thought descision depending on (in most cases) performance issues and not of the "most acknowledged" logical representation. Furtermore, my application logic should be able to handle and get data in a suitable and best possible format. Personally, I'm not scared about wasting storage or break the concept of relational DBS, if it would leed to a massiv performance gain. But its seems like you are quite convinced of the strong relational (NF2,NF3) idea. However, I always CONSIDER alternativs...

Comment: I'm convinced of the idea of using relational data design in a relational database. Performance issues are taken into account when denormalizing. Obviously you're creating a database that is locked in by your application, no other apps can get data from it. Good luck and happpy programming...